# How to make changes to the graphQL schema further than what was created at setup?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, graphql, apollo

So I'm learning GraphQL using Apollo and GraphCool in iOS. From various tutorial I combined, here's the steps I have done.

- Install `npm`
- Install `graphcool` using `npm`
- Install `apollo` CLI using `npm`
- Create new project in Xcode
- Init new graphcool service called "server" within the project folder, which created several files, including `types.graphql` and `package.json`
- Deploy the graphcool "server" service, and get the graphql endpoint.
- Create pod file with `pod Apollo` set for the target
- Do `pod install`
- Open the Xcode workspace created from cocoapod install
- Add apollo run script at build phase
- Put apollo run script phase above the Compile Script phase
- Download apollo schema (`schema.json`)
- Put `schema.json` into the same folder as `AppDelegate.swift`
- Copy `package.json` from "server" folder into the same folder as `AppDelegate.swift`
- Compile the app

Until this step, this is still compiled fine, as this is technically all automatically generated.

- Apollo `API.swift` is generated
- Add `API.swift` to the project

On the automatically generated `types.graphql`, I have type `User`, with element `id`, `name`, and `dateOfBirth`.

```
type User @model {
  id: ID! @isUnique
  name: String
  dateOfBirth: DateTime
}
```

So now, I created another file called `User.graphql` with content like this:

```
query AllUsers {
  allUsers {
    id
    name
  }
}
```

And then compile the app. Until this step, it's still working fine.

So now, I experiment by add new field `telephone` on the `User.graphql`.

```
query AllUsers {
  allUsers {
    id
    name
    telephone
  }
}
```

And then compile. In this step, Xcode starts to give error:

> /User.graphql:5: Cannot query field "telephone" on type "User".

Alright, fair enough. I didn't add field `telephone` on `types.graphql`, so Xcode protests. So I go to `types.graphql` and add `telephone` on the type `User`.

```
type User @model {
  id: ID! @isUnique
  name: String
  dateOfBirth: DateTime
  telephone: String
}
```

After this, I also make sure I do not forget to redeploy the changes to graphcool using `graphcool deploy`.

And then I recompile. The Xcode still gives error that it cannot query field "telephone" on type "User".

**So the question is:** how did I propagate the changes from `types.graphql` that I just add to the type `User`?

I have tried to delete the `API.swift`, and then recompile. But I still get the same error. And the `API.swift` now doesn't even get created if the compile process halted because of errors.

I have the feeling that the solution is very simple, but I have been stuck in this for days and can't find any solution. No tutorial I found discuss about this problem. Those tutorials like assuming that you make changes to `types.graphql`, and Xcode will automatically understand it when interpreting the other graphql files. And on the internet, I can hardly found anyone having the same issue like me.

Can somebody help? Please if someone can help, please do not skip this question.  At least please give me some simple hints on where to look. If you need me to rewrite or reword my question so it become clearer, tell me so in the way you need.

Answer (score 1):

Finally got the answer.

The answer is indeed simple:

After you redeploy the graphcool so that the server now is using the new data types, **redownload** the **schema** (`schema.json`) and replace the old one.

No beginner tutorial ever explain what is the importance of the `schema.json`. It is actually like the "API manual" that stores things like what objects you can query from the server, and what its elements are. Practically, the schema for me is the "translation" of the model in `types.graphql` (and from other graphql files too). Hope other people who is stumbled like me can find this and get unstucked faster.